# Problems with Simultaneous Equation Solving

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

Let me first explain what I am doing and then I will explain the problem that I can't figure out. I am basically trying to solve 2 equations for 2 unknowns (`a1` and `a2`) with some given definitions such as `GL1`  `GL2`  `GC1` and `GC2`. With the given code below, I solved the unknowns in terms of some parameters and (`C1` and `C2`). However, I want to substitute the equations of `C1` and `C2` in the solutions. I tried to put the equations first like given `GL1`  `GL2`  `GC1`... But I didn't get any answers then I tried to  solve it without putting `C1` and `C2` and I got an answer. I now try to substitute those by using `Simplify`, but I don't get any answers again. I need some help to solve these equations. Please check my code below.

```
GL1 = fd a1 t Y1;
GL2 = fd a2 t Y2;
GC1 = (Y1 + Y2) (1 - fd) t p;
GC2 = (Y1 + Y2) (1 - fd) t q;

FullSimplify[
  Solve[((GC1 - GL1) q / (GC2 - GL2) p) (a2/a1) - (C2/Y1)/(C2/Y2) == 0 && 
    a ((GC1/(1 -    fd) - GL1/fd)/C1 + (GC2/(1 - fd) - GL2/fd)/C2) + 
    2 b (1 - 2 fd)/fd (1 - fd) == 0, 
  {a1, a2}] ] 

(*
Solutions: (2 roots for a1 and a2)
{{a1 -> 1/(2 a C2 fd^2 t Y1 (p q Y1^2 - ...,
  a2 -> 1/(2 a C1 fd^2 t Y2 (-p q Y1^2 + ...
 }, 
 {a1 -> 1/(2 a C2 fd^2 t Y1 (p q Y1^2 - ..., 
  a2 -> 1/(2 a C1 fd^2 t Y2 (-p q Y1^2 + ..}}
*)
```

Now as we see solutions are in terms of `C1` and `C2`, I want to substitute these two equations:

```
   C1 =  (1 - t (fd a1 + (1 - fd))) Y1;
   C2 =  (1 - t (fd a2 + (1 - fd))) Y2;
```

When I substitute these equations and try to Simplify I don't get any answers, I think the kernel goes into a infinite loop. Any suggestions.

Comment: I edited your question a bit. Remember: inline code can be made with `` `code` `` anywhere in the text. When you give code-blocks, try to make them copy- and pastable by including only valid *Mathematica* code and putting output into comments. In general, if the code is too large, than people will most likely not look at your question. Since it was only output here, I shortened it!

Comment: To your problem: What you want is just `sol/.{C1 -> (1 - t (fd a1 + (1 - fd))) Y1,  C2 -> (1 - t (fd a2 + (1 - fd))) Y2}`, where `sol` is just a variable containing your solutions for `a1` and `a2`: `sol=Solve[((GC1 - GL1)...,{a1, a2}]`